# Why does the following code result in thread contention

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have the following code

```
public class Test {
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    Test t = new Test();
    Second second = t.new Second();
    second.lock = t.lock;
    Thread thread = new Thread(second);
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    try {
        t.lock.lock();
        System.err.println("got the lock");
    } finally {
        second.shutdown = true;
        t.lock.unlock();
    }
}

private class Second implements Runnable {
    Lock lock;
    volatile boolean shutdown = false;
    int i = 0;

    public void run() {
        while (!shutdown) {
            try {
                lock.lock();
                System.out.println("In second:" + i++);
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I read [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp10264/) that there is a concept of fair and unfair lock, but making locks fair has a big performance impact and nevertheless shouldn't the above code give some fairness to the current thread. 
While actual execution of the above code, the second thread runs forever (gave way for main thread after 545342 iterations)

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically without making the lock fair, the second thread is unlocking and managing to reacquire the lock before the first thread gets a chance to do so. After your large number of iterations, it must have been pre-empted between the "unlock" and the "lock", giving your first thread an opportunity to get in and stop it.

Fundamentally though, you simply shouldn't have code like that in the second thread - under what *real life* situation do you want to repeatedly release and acquire a lock doing *no* work between the two, beyond checking a flag? (And if you *do* want to do that, why do you want to require that a "shutting down" thread acquires the same lock in order to set the flag?)

Comment: well actually this is a sample code, in actual situation there is a lot of work going on between acquiring and releasing locks.
And shutting down was just added to not fill up my console, when main thread acquires lock, just a check here. In reality I have both the threads running forever

Comment: @Raks: It's the amount of work between releasing and then reacquiring the lock which is important, not the work between acquiring and releasing. Basically you need to accept that without making the lock fair, if a thread releases and immediately reacquires a lock, it may not let anything else get a chance.

Comment: But I see the same contention in the actual code, where a lot of processing happens between acquiring an releasing lock. Is addition of Thread.yield() soon after releasing lock in second thread a good idea for preventing this

Comment: @Raks: Please read my previous comment again: it's the processing between *releasing* and then *reacquiring* the lock which is important. You shouldn't see this happen if there's a good chunk of work going on without the second thread owning the lock. I wouldn't advise the use of `Thread.yield` - it may help, but if your design is basically to keep releasing and reacquiring immediately, I'd look at redesigning rather than working round it.